# Spherical plot with ParametricPlot3d

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to plot a  spere with in the colors corresponding to the "height" of each point :

```
R = 1;

h1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (R^2 - x^2 - y^2)^(1/2)}, {x, -1, 
    1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][z]]];

h2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, -(R^2 - x^2 - y^2)^((1/2))}, {x, -1, 
    1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][Abs[z]]]];

Show[h1, h2, PlotRange -> All]
```

This is what I get:  [image]
I tried everything but no succes, I know that I could do the plot with SphericalPlot3D, but I would like to plot it with ParametricPlot3D.

Comment: Try using `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", 1 - z]]` in `h2`.

Comment: See: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html

Comment: That worked, but shouldnt Abs[z] work also ?

Comment: ColorFunctionScaling -> False that works ... I see the problem now . Many thanks to both !

Comment: Yes, my first proposal exploted the fact that you were dealing with a sphere of radius $1$; in general, one has to set `ColorFunctionScaling` properly, as @Julien says.

Comment: Since you define `R` separately, the plot iterators should be `{x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}` and with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` you should change the argument to `ColorData` to `Abs[z/R]`